# Adobe AS3 Air Multitouching on Multiple Points

Tags: actionscript-3, multi-touch

I have 3 randomly scattered buttons on the screen currently, how am I able to make the user tap all the buttons at the same time?

If the player only presses 2 out of the 3 buttons, he/she loses, how do I do this because up till now flash is only detecting 1 button at a time

Comment: You need to enable multi-touch - by default it is off (input mode).  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html#inputMode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell your application to use multiple touch points instead of singular mouse events:

```
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT; //this should be in your main constructor (or first frame of main timeline if using flashPro)
```

Then add touch events

```
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin); //Equivalent of MouseDown event
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove); //Equivalent of MouseMouse Event
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd); //Equivalent of MouseUp event
```

You can find out how many simultaneous touches the device supports with:

```
Multitouch.maxTouchPoints //iOS, windows 8, android all have different max touch points
```

And each touch has an id so you can track which finger is which:

```
   e.touchPointID //e being an instance of a TouchEvent
```

Here is an example application:  http://snipplr.com/view/37220/

Comment: Hm! Okay, I'll try that! Do I need a separate TOUCH_TAP function for each button?

Comment: Could you explain how does the TOUCH_BEGIN and the TOUCH_END works?

Comment: They are equivalent to `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events.